# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire Referenced from:

Tags: ios, cocoapods, dyld

I got this error when I ran my app on my phone
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKrMZ.png)

When I want to add the missing dynamic library, I find that the library is grayish white. Are all the libraries imported through pod like this? It means that the library is missing. I'm looking forward to your help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trMJm.png)

Comment: This question needs more clarity. Copy and past you Podfile. When you say: "I want to add the missing dynamic library" What are your steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you don't have to add the frameworks you installed from your podfile via `pod install` manually. They are all contained in the Pods framework (in your case Pods_ZSS.framework) and added to your project automatically.

Xcode now tries to add Alamofire.framework a second time and does not find the corresponding header search paths, etc. or does not know, which framework should be used.

Try the following:

Remove the additional import of Alamofire, clean build folder and build again.

If the error still occurs, close Xcode and run `pod install` via terminal in your project folder. This configures your Pods project and adds the dependencies to your main project for you.

Also check, if the `target` define in your podfile exactly matches the name of your target in Xcode. E.g. your target in Xcode is named 'SSZ', then your podfile should look something like this:

```
platform :ios, '<your_target_deployment_version>'

# Imports for target 'SSZ'
target 'SSZ' do

  # Use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Frameworks
  pod 'Alamofire', '<specified_framework_version>'
  pod '<second_framework>', '<specified_framework_version>'
  pod '<third_framework>', '<specified_framework_version>'
  # so on and on

end
```

Also remember to open the project's workspace generated after running `pod install` (`<project_name>.xcworkspace`). Otherwise Xcode will not build and integrate your frameworks when building your app. `<project_name>.xcodeproj` just contains your own project without the frameworks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to add the missing alamofire.framework because I saw some other answers, such as adding the missing framework, checking the apple root certificate, etc., or checking the runpath search path, etc. I tried cmd + shift + k and then run `pod install` in shell but  It's still same wrong. Is there a problem with my search path? Anyway, thank you very much

Comment: Thanks for providing your podfile and the screenshots of search paths. I rejected them as edit of my answer, maybe add them to your question for other users trying to help ;) Everything seems correct. One other thing I can think of: do you open your `.xcodeproj` in Xcode? When using cocoapods, you should use the `.xcworkspace` file generated with `pod install`, otherwise your cocoapods won't be compiled and integrated.

Comment: Reviewed my answer regarding opening `.xcworkspace` instead of `.xcodeproj` when using cocoapods.